# JavaScript application is not calculating, please?

Tags: javascript

I am a beginner at JavaScript and I have been working on this very simple project for a couple of days. It is supposed to allow you to calculate the area and perimeter of a rectangle, but despite how much I tweaked the code, it will not calculate when I enter numbers. It should just be a simple user interface that allows you to input into two text boxes:

```js
var $ = function (id) {
    return document.getElementById(id);
}

var calculate_click = function () {
  var width = parseFloat($("width").value);
  var length = parseFloat($("length").value);

  $("area").value = "";
  $("perimeter").value = "";

  if (isNaN(width) || width <= 0) {
    alert("Width must be a valid number and greater than zero.");
  }
  else if (isNaN(length) || width <= 0) {
    alert("Length must be a valid number and greater than zero.");
  } else {
    var area = width * length;
    var perimeter = 2 * width + 2 * length;

    $("area").value = area;
    $("perimeter").value = perimeter;
  }

  window.onload = function () {
    $("calculate").onclick = calculate_click;
    $("length").focus();
  }
}
```

```css
body {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    background: #333366; }
#content {
    width: 450px;
    margin: 10px auto;
    padding: 5px 20px;
    background: white;
    border: thin solid black; }
#salesTax, #total {
    color: black; }
#taxCalc label {
    display: block;
    width: 6em;
    text-align: right;
    padding-right: 1em;
    float: left; }
#taxCalc input {
    display: block;
    float: left; }
#taxCalc br {
    clear: left; }
​
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Area and Perimeter Calculator</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="sales_tax.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="sales_tax.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="content">
    <h2>Area and Perimeter Calculator</h2>
    <p>Enter the values below and click "Calculate".</p>
    <div id="taxCalc">
        <label for="length">Length:</label>
        <input type="text" id="length" /><br />

        <label for="width">Width:</label>
        <input type="text" id="width" /><br />

        <label for="area">Area:</label>
        <input type="text" id="area" disabled="disabled" /><br />

        <label for="perimeter">Perimeter:</label>
        <input type="text" id="total" disabled="disabled" /><br />

        <label>&nbsp;</label>
        <input type="button" id="calculate" value="Calculate" /><br />
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
​
```

If anyone can please help even a little, I would genuinely appreciate it,
Thank you.

Comment: you have a missing `v` in `ar $ = function (id) {` - should be `var $ = function (id) {`

Comment: Oh, sorry. I pasted it wrong, but the actual JS file has the "var". Can I edit my post? Thank you for replying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were two problems with your script (Well technically three, but I think the missing v at the beginning was a copy/paste mistake.

1st: The `window.onload` functions needs to be outside `calculate_click`. It never gets called, because the `calculate_click` never gets called.

2nd: The input for perimeter, had `id="total"`, but you were calling `$("perimeter")`. This is fixed in the jsfiddle.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/eoj2td8y/) is a working form.

Comment: Ohhh, now I understand. I obviously need to do more practice exercises. Thank you so much!! <3